# Get values ​and keys less than 30

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, list

I'm trying to fetch the values ​​from the list when the value is less than thirty days ?

```
var list = 
[
    [ '*.cervepar.com.py', 45 ],
    [ '*.fnc.com.uy', 44 ],
    [ '*.btg360.com.br', 369 ],
    [ '*.reservapto.com.br', 361 ],
    [ '*.koerich.com.br', 550 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ],
    [ '*.cbn.com.bo', 21 ],
    [ '*.compassouol.com', 203 ],
    [ '*.cerchile.cl', 443 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `.filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter` like this:

```js
var list = 
[
    [ '*.cervepar.com.py', 45 ],
    [ '*.fnc.com.uy', 44 ],
    [ '*.btg360.com.br', 369 ],
    [ '*.reservapto.com.br', 361 ],
    [ '*.koerich.com.br', 550 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ],
    [ '*.cbn.com.bo', 21 ],
    [ '*.compassouol.com', 203 ],
    [ '*.cerchile.cl', 443 ],
    [ '*.compasso.com.br', 162 ]
];

let filteredArr = list.filter(x => x[1] < 30);
console.log(filteredArr);
```